# How can I delete assets specified in pubspec.yaml in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, assets

In my flutter app, I need an asset just for the first start of the app and want to delete it afterwards. Is that possible?

I'm primarily using flutter for Android, so a platform specific answer would also be appreciated, if it's not possible to do with Dart Code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible currently.

> The rootBundle contains the resources that were packaged with the
> application when it was built. To add resources to the rootBundle for
> your application, add them to the assets subsection of the flutter
> section of your application's pubspec.yaml manifest.

It's packaged with the app on build time, and it can't be modified.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you enable to read your assets anytime and handle the possibility of displaying in your code by condition.

Comment: I want my app to take as little storage as possible, so to guarentee this, I would need to delete the asset later, if the user wants that.

Comment: Let's try Sqlite alternatively. Because if your assets contain in your app even if you declare in pubspect file or not.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean but in my case, I want to preload some images with the app. Don't know how sqlite could help me. I still need to reference the assets through the pubspec.yaml file to my understanding.